# How to Delete a Row with DataTables Plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to delete a row using the DataTables plugin. First I don't get the example at all.

What I have this is a user checks the row they want to delete. I do this then

```
var row = $('#id :checked').parents('tr');
```

So I get the row of the checked checkbox. Lets assume they only check one box( if multiple where choose it might be different - might need a jquery each loop).

I then try to do this

```
var position = GlobalVariable.fnGetPosition(row);
GlobalVariable.fnDeleteRow(position);
```

position is always null and So I have no clue how to do this.

http://datatables.net/api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that something like the following piece of code should work:

```
$('#id :checked').each(function(index){
   GlobalVariable.fnDeleteRow($(this).parents('tr')[0]);
});
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work from what the API and their examples say.

Comment: how do you use this method to delete rows that are not in the dom? (like ones on the next page).  Deleting by index is huge pain as it re-orders after every delete.